# How can I use a variable as global in my controller?

Tags: express, model-view-controller, view, parameters, controller

I want to use a variable called "user" in every view, i think a way to solve this is to shared the variable from the controler to the views, but I have 20 views, so I don't want to add 20 times the variable in every method of my controller. For example, here I'm sharing the variable user, to the view profile, but I want to use this variable in all views:

```
profile: (req,res) => {
 if (req.session.user) {
      res.render("profile",{user:req.session.user})
 }
 else{
      res.render("login")
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [res.locals](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals) is for.  Template engines will automatically search `res.locals` for any variable that you reference in your template so if you put it there, then you don't have to pass it manually to every `res.render()` call.

So, you could make middleware that is defined before your controller routing like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session.user) {
        res.locals.user = req.session.user;
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
});
```

Then, your controller endpoint can just be this:

```
profile: (req,res) => {
   res.render("profile");
}
```

If `req.session.user` exists, it will put the `user` object into `res.locals` where the template can just reference `user` and the template engine will find it for you (just the same as if you passed it to `res.render()`.

If `req.session.user` does not exist, then the middleware will redirect to `/login`.  This is generally better than rendering the login page for a URL that is actually your profile URL.  The rendered content should match the URL.

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved the problem!!!

Comment: @ManuelAlejandroGarcaAndrade - Since it appears you may be new here, I'll explain that you can indicate to the community here that this solved your problem and answered the question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you a few reputation points for following that procedure.